# Looking for a simple tool to update a table

Tags: table

What I would like. A server generates row entries every now and then. I want this entry to be sent to my WordPress site and inserted as a row in a table.

How would I accomplish this as simply and securely as possible.

My knowledge of WordPress development is in its infancy stage.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress has an API available to allow external scripts to get data from your website and to add (POST) data to your website.
You can [create a custom API endpoint](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/) where you receive the data from the other server and in a simple function create a new record in the WordPress database:

1. Create a function in your functions.php to create a new record in the tablet.
2. Add the new API endpoint in your functions.php

I know this is a very summarized explanation, but I hope this gets you in the right direction?